# GeoServer/QGIS labeling

Tags: qgis, geoserver, labeling

I exported SLD file from QGIS for a polygon layer and uploaded both the style and the layer on GeoServer. The layer in question below:

[image]

For some reason the label appears three times at the shown scale and as I zoom in it starts multiplying. And the Min/MaxScaleDenominator doesn't work on the label either.

Here is the code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" version="1.1.0" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se">
  <NamedLayer>
    <se:Name>project_hoorkommun_visu</se:Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <se:Name>project_hoorkommun_visu</se:Name>
      <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <se:Rule>
         
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#e3e987</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#388036</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          
          <se:TextSymbolizer>
            <se:Label>
              <ogc:PropertyName>kommunnamn</ogc:PropertyName>
            </se:Label>
            <se:Font>
              <se:SvgParameter name="font-family">Georgia</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="font-size">18</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="font-weight">bold</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Font>
            <se:LabelPlacement>
              <se:PointPlacement>
                <se:AnchorPoint>
                  <se:AnchorPointX>0.5</se:AnchorPointX>
                  <se:AnchorPointY>0.5</se:AnchorPointY>
                </se:AnchorPoint>
              </se:PointPlacement>
            </se:LabelPlacement>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#323232</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
          </se:TextSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
      </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: don't request tiles for the labels or specify a centroid to draw the label at

Comment: Where in the code am I requesting tiles? (I'm quite new to this)

Comment: you haven't posted any client code so I can't tell but that is almost certainly your problem

Comment: What's a client code? (Sorry )

Comment: the client is how you display the map

Comment: I'm using html to call Geoserver and display the map in a browser. Is client html in this case?

Comment: You can set 'tiled' attribute to false in geoserver layer configuration or pass argument 'tiled=false' with the URL that you pass to geoserver for getting the layer. It is more of layer configuration and not related to SLD configuration.